# Int64 object type length

Tags: powershell, centrify

I am new to powershell so it would be great if someone could help me to understand best practice for this case:

I am using Centrify Powershell module to fetch users' uid property. If I type

`Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | select name,uid`

It returns following:

```
markok                   3252423756
markusa                  32356514982
markusk                    417
markusp                  32187
```

I need to filter out `uid` length. so I tried

```
Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | ? {($_.Uid).length -lt 6 } | select name,uid
```

but it keeps returning users with `uid` longer than 6 characters long. 
So I tried to find out the length of each `uid`:

```
Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | %{($_.uid).length}
```

**and**

```
Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | %{($_.uid).count}
```

but itreturns `1` for each `uid` which is obviously not true.

So I decided to find out the type of `uid` property by `Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | %{($_.uid).gettype()}` and the object type is `Int64   System.ValueType`

I have managed to find a way around by using `tostring()` method:

```
Get-CdmUserProfile -Zone "DN_NAME_HERE" | %{(($_.uid).tostring()).length}
```

It does it's job, but I am not sure if it's the best practice in terms of performance and neat typing. Is there any other way of finding out `int64` object length?

**TL;DR**

What is the best practice to find int64 length?

Comment: There isn't really a "best way" in this scenario, but you've found the easiest way and I'd suggest using the way that works and is readable.  You can also do: `| ? { "$($_.uid)".Length -lt 6 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, converting it to a string and getting the length.

If you really want a mathematical way to get the number of digits in an `Integer`, you can use the `[Math]::Log10` function with the `[Math]::Truncate` function:

`$digitsLong = [Math]::Truncate( [Math]::Log10( $uid ) + 1 )`